# Hang 3 flat-screen monitors from a tilted wooden beam

Tags: wood, attic, mounting, screens

I have an attic with a part where the floor was removed to bring light to the living room. I'd like to have my desk adjacent to that emptyness, but there's no space on the desk to place screens so I'd like to have them hanging above the emptyness.

Now it's pretty easy to find a desktop mount for 3 monitors that is attached to the desk (such as the Duronic DM553 Spring Triple), but I haven't found anything that would let me hang screens from the ceiling.

Furthermore, the mount should be screwed into the tilted wooden beam already present since the ceiling isn't plan, it is tilted ~30°.

My google-fu has failed me, any ideas?

EDIT: picture of the beam[image]

Comment: What size beam is this being attached to? Are you sure it can bear the load of three screens?

Comment: If [three of these](http://wallmountworldblog.com/2012/02/24/wallmountworld-long-arm-lcd-wall-mount-bracket-fits-vesa-200x200-200x100-100x100-lcd-led-tv-and-display-with-removable-mount-adaptor-plate-black.aspx) will work I'll draw it up as an answer. Wall, ceiling, it's all the same. Standard VESA mount as well, so your LCD must support that. It extends three ft from the 'wall', you didn't state the dropdown height you require.

Comment: @BigHomie The beam is massive, like 20x30cm

Comment: @BigHomie What you linked doesn't work because the beam is tilted, attaching 3 of those to each face of the beam will result in non-aligned screens

Comment: Can u post a pic of the beam?

Comment: Try "monitor ceiling mount" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Craig I did that with DDG, Google & Amazon, to no avail. There's always a part that won't tilt.
A custom made solution is required here I think.

Comment: Take a [closer look](http://images.quickblogcast.com/3/8/0/7/0/217356-207083/UAE_40.jpg?a=13). It has four hinges, two places that swivel. Still no?

Comment: Why are you opposed to the stand being attached to the desk? Would be easier, cheaper and likely more secure. It also makes it easier for you to reposition the desk at a later day. If you want to mount it off the beam you're going to have to hang something off the beam which will be visible. Less visually intrusive to use the desk mount. There are a number of triple monitor stands available.

Comment: Without an adjustable length, the screens won't be at the same height..

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY because there's no enough room to attach the stand to the desk, there's another beam behind that you don't see. There's just enough room for a chair and keyboard.

Comment: The stand clamps on to the desk and takes up maybe 4-6 square inches of desk space. A chair and a keyboard are set on different planes so not sure what that has to do with anything. You don't put a chair on your desk. Having a hard time picturing exactly what you want to do. Might be helpful if you come up with a sketch of the space and where you want to put the desk, chair and monitor.

Comment: Possible duplicate, believe it or not: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/22183/how-should-i-mount-a-tv-to-a-wall-that-slants-inwards-8-degrees

Answer (score 1):

Is mounting a triangle shaped **hardwood block** to reduce or eliminate the 30 degree angle out of the question? I would lag-bolt it to the beam and then mount the ceiling mount to that in the usual manner.

There are plenty of long extension monitor/TV ceiling mounts available which with the appropriate length, put the monitors at eye-level, but as you've found, 20 degrees is as much as the ceiling end will compensate for.

Also, several of the multi-monitor mounts use a chrome tube and the brackets are movable up and down the tube by a thumb screw arrangement. Nothing prevents you from changing the chrome tube out for your own custom length one that would extend from a drilled hole in the beam down to a floor or desk mounting block.

Having it supported on both ends also means you're not sporting a really expensive pendulum that bounces around in air currents or from the garbage truck rolling down the street.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea